# Why is the Chrome extension's toolbar icon getting reset to the default icon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In this minimal example, I have the following *manifest.json*:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["webNavigation", "activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
          "16": "red.png"
      }
  }
}
```

On every navigation, I want to change the icon in the toolbar to a green png. It works, however, there's a problem:

1. I'm on any page, the icon is green.
2. I click on a link, it triggers navigation.
3. The icon resets back to red for a few milliseconds
4. My listeners get triggered, and they set the icon back to green.

My *background.js*:

```
const setIcon = (details) => {
    if (details.frameId != 0) {
        return; // only update the icon for main page, not iframe/frame
    }
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: { '16' : 'green.png'},
        tabId: details.tabId
    });
}
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(setIcon);
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(setIcon);
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(setIcon);
```

What causes this behavior? Is there a way I can prevent the icon getting reset on navigation?

Comment: This is how it is implemented in Chrome. You can complain on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile a workaround would be to have a neutral gray icon as default in manifest.json and change to red or green in a listener.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1029367

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the link. I wonder why there's no option to make the change permanent.

Comment: Eh? Because no one implemented it.